# How to extract a date and some other numerical values from a String in Java?

Tags: java, android, regex

In String have Some text like

> Some texts bhla bhla. You have 50% off on your orders. Some texts.. Valid till 29 Jul

How can i extract the `50%` and `29 Jul` from the String?
I don't know how to do this.
Which is best way to extract the offer percentage and validate the date from that String?

For this can i use `regex` or any other process to extract it.

Help me to solve this issue.

Comment: Why does you attempted code not use the same input that your requirements use? You should actually attempt something, not just post some regex related code that doesn't relate to your problem

Comment: Google for regular expressions.

Comment: @musefan okay ill remove it.

Comment: @Yugesh: Don't remove it. Change it to try and solve your problem yourself, then let us know what you get stuck with

Comment: Try and code something with [this regex](https://regex101.com/r/gN7nZ0/1)

Comment: @musefan Thanks. Already Know about regex but not that much. Now only going to learn in depth.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess using Pattern and Matcher is the most convinent way

```
String text = "You have 50% off on your orders. Some texts.. Valid till 29 Jul";
Pattern pat = Pattern.compile("\\d+%");
Matcher match = pat.matcher(text);
if (match.find()) {
     System.out.println(match.group(0));
}
Pattern pat2 = Pattern.compile("\\d{1,2}\\s[A-z]{3}");
match = pat2.matcher(text);
if (match.find()) {
    System.out.println(match.group(0));
}
```

> 50%
>   
>   29 Jul

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like

```
(\d+%).*?(\d{1,2}\s+(?:jan|feb|mar|apr|may|jun|jul|aug|sep|oct|nov|dec))
```

You'll get two capture groups. The first holding the percentage, the second the date.

[See it here at regex101](https://regex101.com/r/nU6rV4/1).

Answer (score -1):

You have to use Pattern to define a regular expression and a Matcher to find it in the text.

For example, if you know your verification codes are numbers with more than 6 digits, you can do:

```
final String text1 = "Your Verification Code is 6457891";

final Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("[0-9]{7,}");
final Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(text1);
if (matcher.find()) {
    System.out.println(matcher.group()); //Prints 6457891
}
```

In order to find dates, percentages or whatever, you have to compile a Pattern with the Regular Expression that fits to your requirements, and apply it.

By using Pattern and Matcher you can go further than just find your value, and you can know the start position in the string, the end, the number of occurrences and many other helpful things.

Here you can find [Pattern](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html) and [Matcher](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html) official documentation.

Answer (score -1):

you can use substring() method of String by spilt it according to your requirement for e.g. split it with til for date and for % use indexof() function and get index of have and off then get the middle string by substring().

Comment: it's may be not efficient way for it but what's error in that?